# quarkus-hibernate-orm complains about no suitable persistence unit for `PanacheEntity` and `PanacheEntityBase`

Tags: kotlin, quarkus, quarkus-panache

Warning message

> WARN  [io.qua.hib.orm.dep.HibernateOrmProcessor] Could not find a suitable persistence unit for model classes:
> - io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin.PanacheEntity
> - io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin.PanacheEntityBase

The same issue with both `io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache` and `io.quarkus:quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin` (PanacheCompanion).

My project has multiple named persistent units and datasources (no default). I'm also using multitenant feature.

> INFO  [io.quarkus] Installed features: [agroal, cache, cdi, config-yaml, hibernate-orm, hibernate-orm-panache-kotlin, jdbc-mysql, kotlin, mutiny, narayana-jta, resteasy, resteasy-jackson, security, smallrye-context-propagation, smallrye-jwt, smallrye-openapi, swagger-ui, vertx, vertx-web]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ORM processor doesn't exclude those base entities, and tries to attach them to a non-existent "default" persistent units. Hence the warning.

I could get rid of it by either define "default" PU or assign `io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin` to a named one.

```yaml
quarkus:
  hibernate-orm:
    dummy:
      packages: io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.panache.kotlin
      datasource: dummy
```

Comment: But this requires dummy datasource?